# Microsoft Graph 403 Forbidden when getting /v1.0/me

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm having a bit of a difficult time trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've registered an application with Azure portal and I keep getting a 403 error after the Oauth2 is completed and when I request the user data when hitting `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`

Full error:

```
    Client error: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
{"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.","innerError":{"date":"2022-11-29T21:40:18","request-id":"cc4628ee-4ab4-4eec-8766-9e3290ba4451","client-request-id":"cc4628ee-4ab4-4eec-8766-9e3290ba4451"}}}
```

I'm using the PHP SDK to do this, and I had it working with another app but with this new app I can't seem to do it.

This is the API Permissions I have available for the Application:
[image]

There are so many permissions, i'm not sure why I'm getting 403? I don't see what scope I'm missing? On the PHP SDK side, I've included all the scopes as in the image.

Comment: You need to show your authentication code eg are you requesting those scopes or using the wrong authentication flow etc ? You can check you token in jwt.io to see what permissions are included in it.

Comment: User.read permission is sufficient for calling me endpoint . you can try to check the endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me in graph explorer , if its working fine? , then definitely there is some issue in your code , kindly help us with which auth flow you are using and provide the code .

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment.***

Here I used client credential flow to get the token

[image]

I tried to query the graph /me end point , it requires delegated authentication .

Calling the `https://graph.microsoft.com/me` endpoint needs  a signed-in user and so a  delegated permission.

[image]

So even if the delegated permission is given , if client credentials flow is used as grant_typy ,  there will be 403 forbidden error.

I tried the same with authorization code flow and could sign in user and get details successfully.

[image]

Another criteria ,I tried the same for users endpoint

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`

[image]

**Required permissions:**

[image]

Here the admin consent is not granted for the User.Read.All application permission

[image]

- Make sure the application permissions required for your query are granted admin consent directly through portal or during authentication of user account with which the query is made.

[image]

***Then the request can be queried successfully.***

[image]

**Reference:** [Get a user - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)